# Python: How to fix, if a static class variable gets a different function reference pointer?

Tags: python, reference, static, function-pointers, class-variables

I wonder why my class calls the referenced function (assigned to a static class variable) with with an argument. If I assign the function reference to a normal class variable it works like expected.

Here my example code:

```
# This function is not editable, because it's imported from an API
def getStuff(): 
    print "I do my stuff!!!"

class foo(object):
    GET_STUFF = getStuff

    def __init__(self):
        print "static var: ",self.GET_STUFF
        self.GET_STUFF()

print "outer func: ",getStuff
foo()
```

This comes up with the following error:

```
outer func:  <function getStuff at 0x0000000003219908>
static var:  <bound method foo.getStuff of <__main__.foo object at 0x00000000030AB358>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/example.py", line 13, in <module>
    foo()
  File "C:/example.py", line 10, in __init__
    self.GET_STUFF()
TypeError: getStuff() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

To fix  this issue I point the function reference inside the constructor to the class variable:

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.GET_STUFF = getStuff
        print "static var: ",self.GET_STUFF
        self.GET_STUFF()
```

The result is like expected and works fine:

```
outer func:  <function getStuff at 0x000000000331F908>
static var:  <function getStuff at 0x000000000331F908>
I do my stuff!!!
```

**But:**

I wanted to use a static class variable, because it makes it easy to read and simple to setup for different API's. So in the end I would come up with some wrapper classes like in the following:

```
from API01 import getStuff01
from API02 import getStuff02

# bar calculates stuff object from the API (it calls GET_STUFF)
# and stores the object into self.stuff
import bar 

class foo01(bar):
    GET_STUFF = getStuff01

    def DoSomething(self, volume):
        self.stuff.volume = volume

class foo02(bar):
    GET_STUFF = getStuff02

    def DoSomething(self, volume):
        self.stuff.volume = volume

# [...] and so on..
```

Is there a way to bring it to work in the way I want to setup my wrapper classes, or do I really have to define a constructor for each wrapper class?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought already that my object is calling the referenced function with itself as argument. After a bit of research I finally found a solution. When I use a class variable to point to a function it will not referencing a direct pointer. It references the function as a bounced method of it's class. To get rid of the default call of calling a method with `getattr`, the call function of `getattr` for the class itself has to be overwritten (in this case the class `bar`, because `foo` (the wrapper classes) inherits the functionalities of `bar`:

```
import inspect

class bar(object):
    GET_STUFF = None

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        attr = object.__getattribute__(self,name)
        if name == "GET_STUFF":
            # Check: is method and is bounced?
            if inspect.ismethod(attr) and attr.im_self is not None:
                return attr.__func__
        return attr
```

`getattr` of `bar` is now pointing to the original function reference, but only for the class variable `GET_STUFF`, because I want to leave the default functionality for the rest of my variables.

So, when I now execute the following:

```
 class foo(bar):
    GET_STUFF = getStuff

    def __init__(self):
        print "inner func: ",self.GET_STUFF
        self.GET_STUFF()

foo()
```

I get the expected result and can write my wrappers without producing additional code for each module with those wrapper classes:

```
outer func:  <function getStuff at 0x00000000034259E8>
inner func:  <function getStuff at 0x00000000034259E8>
I do my stuff!!!
```

Comment: This may also help: https://julien.danjou.info/blog/2013/guide-python-static-class-abstract-methods

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the error is that

```
self.GET_STUFF()
```

actually means

```
tmp = getattr(self, 'GET_STUFF')
tmp(self)
```

That means these two classes are equivalent:

```
def foo(self): pass

class Foo(object):
     a = foo

class Bar(object):
     def a(self): pass
```

In both cases, a function object is added to the class as a member and that means for Python that the function wants `self` as the first parameter.

To achieve what you want:

```
from API01 import getStuff01

def wrapper01(self):
    getStuff01()

class foo01(object):
    GET_STUFF = wrapper01
```

Comment: Thanks, that's an easy solution for this situation, but I think not really useful for my case, because I am writing a kind of API which will be used by other developers in the end. That's the reason I want the structure as simple as possible to use the API. In this case the developer has to make sure to create the additional function in every module he uses `bar` as parent of his classes. I found a different solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Just for extend Aaron answer, if you want to have static methods you can use the @staticmethod decorator:

```
class Calc:

  @staticmethod
  def sum(x, y):
    return x + y

print (Calc.sum(3,4))

>>> 7
```